# text type in mysql primary keyed and unique by default

Tags: mysql

I have created some tables in mysql database and I don't understand why all of the text types are primary keyed and unique by default.

Anyone got any idea?

This is the query I got from phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE TABLE temp ( 
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
random varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
history text, PRIMARY KEY (id) )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: I guess because you made them that way

Comment: no..i did not..thats the whole point

Comment: How did you create? Show the script you wrote.

Comment: Can you upload a picture.

Comment: Actually I created my table using phpmyadmin...is that the problem

Comment: CREATE TABLE `temp` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `random` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `history` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: above is the query i got from phpmyadmin

Comment: The query you added will not make your `history` column `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY`.

Comment: well I can see that....thats why asking this question here..in phpmydmin is does show it to be unique and primary